# .img-fluid bootstrap 4 на IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, bootstrap4, ie11

Подскажите, почему не работает адаптация изображений от bootstrap 4 на IE 11? Задаю изображению стиль img-fluid по высота остается изначальной, то есть изображение становится вытянутым по вертикали.
Вот скриншоты при разной ширине экрана:
http://prntscr.com/l03y22
http://prntscr.com/l03y5q

Comment: Ваши скрины не информативны, глядя на них все работает нормально. Добавьте прямо в вопрос [mcve]. Чтобы понять в чем у вас проблема нужен код. Очевидно у вас где-то ошибка, тк 4ый бутстрап поддерживает ие от 10ки.

Comment: @kizoso в чем именно они не информативны? На широком экране баннер нормальный, а на узком вытянут в высоту - вы этого не видите?

Comment: без кода невозможно понять что у вас там